# PHP Loop stdClass Object

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have a call to a webservice which is returning json data. I use:

```
$response_json = json_decode ( $response );
```

If I print_r($response) I get this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [meta] => stdClass Object
    (
        [no_of_pages] => 3
        [current_page] => 1
        [max_items_per_page] => 250
        [no_of_items] => 740
    )

[data] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [orderid] => 322191645
                [customer] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [city] => FELIXSTOWE
```

I am trying to loop through the orders:

```
foreach($response_json as $orders) {
    echo $orders.['data'].[0].['orderid'];
    }
```

but I keep getting:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string. I have also tried many other ways, but I just can't seem to access the data in a loop. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can json_decode as associative array.

```
$response = json_decode ($response, true);

foreach($response as $orders) {
    echo $orders[0]['orderid'];
}
```

Comment: OK if I do: $response_json = json_decode ( $response , true);
  
  foreach($response_json as $orders) {
  echo $orders.['data'].[0].['orderid'];

Comment: echo $orders['data'][0]['orderid']; I get no output with this??

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my answer. Its without ['data'] as you loop already through the array. To be sure do "print_r($orders);"

Comment: Sorry don't know what I am doing wrong here... foreach($response_json as $orders) {    
    foreach($orders as $order) {
     echo $order['orderid'];  
        }}  Only outputs 2 orders with Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: Loop through ***$response_json['data']***

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't use dots between brackets.
2. Skip "data" in your array.

Example:

```
foreach($response_json as $orders) {
    echo $orders[0]['orderid'];
}
```